# Deleting a button onclick from a class

Tags: javascript, onclick, this

`onclick` of a button with a `class` of `obliterate`, I want to have my following code take a bunch of identical buttons, besides its unique id and then delete it. The Buttons can be through innerHTML at any time from user input. I want to remove the button `onclick`, after a `confirm` This is my current code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('obliterate').onclick = function() {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')){
         //get this then remove it with remove(this.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you just want to remove the element that was clicked ?

Comment: basically yes, but since its not in existence onload and I don't want to do .innerHTML = '<button Onclick = "remove(this.id)">' I don't know what to do. (this is not my real code) .

Comment: So what you're asking now, is really how to create a delegated event handler in plain javascript ?

Comment: im sorry, but i have no idea what that means...

Comment: Looking back on this. Wow, I've learned so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be straight forward, attach event handler to elements, remove element

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.obliterate');

for (var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        if ( confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') ) {
            this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

---

If the elements don't exist on pageload, you have to delegate, and doing that without library can be somewhat complicated, depending on what selector you want to match, if there are children inside the clicked element etc. but here's a simlified version

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var clicked = event.target;
    var elems   = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.obliterate'));

    if ( elems.indexOf(clicked) !== -1 ) {
        if ( confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?') ) {
            clicked.parentNode.removeChild(clicked);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/58w93k0z/)

Comment: Better now :-) (and I discarded my "in the works" answer)

Comment: Yeah, somehow the loop dissapeared on me !

Comment: But I must say that `querySelectorAll` isn't really needed here. `getElementsByClassName` would be just as good and probably outperform...

Comment: But `querySelectorAll` has better browser support, which is why I prefer it.

Comment: Hmmm.. Which browser(s) support `qSA` and not `getByClass...`?

Comment: IE8 does, but I guess noone cares about that anymore, it's just old habit, QSA has better support in older browser than `getByClass...`

Comment: And in older browsers that do support `getByClass` it's slow as hell, newer browsers have dramatically improved searching the DOM for classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bind` function to provide context so in your case:

```
element.onclick = function(){ ... }.bind(this);
```

Comment: I'm using a class... how do i go like document.getElementsByClassName('obliterate').onclick = function(){}.bind(this);